# Indy TIdIPMCastServer - No route to host

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm trying to use the Indy TIdIPMCastServer in order to send a message to a group of clients. But all I get is 'Socket Error # 10065 No route to host.'. What am I doing wrong?

```
unit MCSender;

interface

uses
  Classes, IdGlobal, IdSocketHandle, IdIPMCastServer, IdIPMCastClient;

type
  TSBUDPSender = class(TComponent)
  private
    FMCSender: TIdIPMCastServer;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Send(Data: string); overload;
  end;

implementation

uses
  IdStack, SysUtils;

{ TSBUDPSender }

constructor TSBUDPSender.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FMCSender := TIdIPMCastServer.Create(Self);
  FMCSender.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
  FMCSender.MulticastGroup := '224.0.0.1';
  FMCSender.Port := 19151;
end;

destructor TSBUDPSender.Destroy;
begin
  FMCSender.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TSBUDPSender.Send(Data: string);
var
  BS: TBytesStream;
  B: TBytes;
begin
  if not FMCSender.Active then
    FMCSender.Active := True;

  BS := TBytesStream.Create;
  try
    B := BytesOf(UTF8Encode(Data));
    BS.Write(B[0], Length(B));
    FMCSender.Send(TidBytes(Copy(BS.Bytes, 0, BS.Size)));
  finally
    BS.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure Test;
var
  SBSender: TSBUDPSender;
begin
  SBSender := TSBUDPSender.Create(nil);
  try
    SBSender.Send('ABC');
  finally
    SBSender.Free;
  end;
end;

initialization
  Test;
end.
```

I'm using Delphi 10.4.1 with the included Indy version.

Comment: The code looks fine, though you are not setting the server's `BoundIP`/`BoundPort` properties. You should consider binding the server to a specific NIC that you want to send from, and a specific Port to send from. Otherwise, a random NIC/Port will be used, which may or may not work in your case. However, `224.0.0.1` is a special-case multicast IP address for "all hosts on the network". An error on that IP might imply an issue with your OS's routing tables, or a misconfiguration in your network router. Do you have the same error if you send to an IP of a specific multicast group instead?

Comment: Also, unrelated to your issue, but your `TSBUDPSender.Send()` code is overly complicated. `TIdIPMCastServer.Send()` has an overload that takes in a `string` and optional `IIdTextEncoding` as input. That code can be simplified to this: `procedure TSBUDPSender.Send(Data: string); begin FMCSender.Send(Data, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8); end;`

Comment: The error is not shown if I set `BoundIP`/`BoundPort`. The error also goes away if I leave `BoundIP`/`BoundPort` empty and set `MulticastGroup` to values like `224.0.0.2`, `224.0.0.100`, `224.0.0.251` or `224.0.0.252`.

Comment: That implies that `224.0.0.1` is not valid in your network configuration, you will have to double-check that